# configure keyboard shortcut to enable/disable chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts, google-chrome-extensions

Is there a way to configure a keyboard shortcut for enabling or disabling Chrome extensions? I want to disable extensions by default and enable them only when needed.

Comment: for those looking an open source app to quick enable disable: http://sergiokas.github.io/Extensity/

Answer (score 6):

I know exactly what you mean. I have several extensions installed but only need them occasionally. I use the [SimpleExtManager](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/simpleextmanager/kniehgiejgnnpgojkdhhjbgbllnfkfdk) to enable and disable extensions via the keyboard.

---

**Setup**

1. Install SimpleExtManager from the Chrome Web Store
2. Add a keyboard shortcut in Chrome to activate SimpleExtManager

   - Hamburger Menu > More Tools > Extensions > Scroll to the bottom > click `Keyboard shortcuts` > and set a keyboard shortcut.

[image: Keyboard shortcuts]

Example: <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>3</kbd>

[image: Set keyboard shortcut]

3. (Optional) Configure the options for SimpleExtManager to

   - Show search box
   - Search bar & buttons on top
   - Remember search bar state

[image: SimpleExtManager Options]

[image: Set SimpleExtManager Options]

---

**Use**

1. Now, to enable an extension, use your keyboard shortcut to activate SimpleExtManager
2. Search for an extension
3. Use the arrow keys (<kbd>⬇</kbd>) to navigate to the extension
4. Hit the <kbd>Space</kbd> to enable the extension

   - Tap the <kbd>Space</kbd> bar again to disable to extension

---

**In action**

[image: SimpleExtManager in action]